# Imu data about xsens_driver

Tags: ros, imu, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i got the sensor_msgs::Imu data by adding listener to the topic, but before i use the imu data, how could i judge the imu.linear_acceleration or imu.angular_velocity is valid or available. i saw the imu.linear_acceleration.x default value is -1f, so it dosen't have a easy way(or flag) to judge if i could use the data,  right ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255664/imu-data-about-xsens_driver/) by [apanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29296/apanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`-1` means invalid. See the documentation here: http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29296/apanda/) on 2017-03-02**:
I mean it's a float or double, so i can't judge if it's invalid by "==", is there a common way, like imu.isValid or imu.linear_acceleration.isValid. Thanks.
BTW, linear_acceleration.x, y, z could be -1f, not defualt.